# Why does convolution become multiplication when taking the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Why is it, that if I have a convolution and I take the Fourier Transform, it becomes a multiplication?

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for the edit !

Comment: You could make your own research, it is in every course on the Fourier transform

Comment: @user1952009: this is a quite legitimate question. I have learnt the analytical arguments, but I realize that I still have never been truly explained this behavior.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ?? The answer I wrote is in every course on the Fourier transform. See for example there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: @user1952009: right, this is precisely what I learnt as well and which sheds no light.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean with "sheds no light" ? On what ? What do you want more ?

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for the link, but I agree with YvesDaoust, it's not so trivial.

Comment: @totyped I didn't say it is trivial, I said "you could make your own research, it is in every course"... And stop trolling, thank you.

Comment: Guys... calm down. Haha... Thanks a lot to user1952009 for taking you time .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything converges absolutely, with the change of variable $y = t-x$ :
$$\mathcal{F}[g(x)](\xi)\ \mathcal{F}[h(x)](\xi) = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)  e^{-2i \pi\xi x}dx\right)\left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)  e^{-2i \pi\xi x}dx\right)$$ $$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) h(y) e^{-2i \pi\xi x}e^{-2i \pi\xi y}dxdy= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) h(t-x) e^{-2i \pi\xi x}e^{-2i \pi\xi (t-x)}dxdt$$ $$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) h(t-x) dx\right)e^{-2i \pi\xi t} dt=\mathcal{F}[g\ast h(x)](\xi)$$

The opposite direction needs the Fourier inversion theorem, with $G(\xi) = \mathcal{F}[g(x)](\xi), H(\xi ) =\mathcal{F}[h(x)](\xi)$, and since the inverse Fourier transform is essentially the same operator as the Fourier transform, it means that
$$g \ast h(x) =  \mathcal{F}^{-1}[G(\xi)H(\xi)](x) \quad \implies \quad G \ast H(\xi) =  \mathcal{F}[g(x) h(x)](\xi)$$

Comment: looks good, but needs a bit more work on the integral. dx missing in first tow integrals and suppsitiution from x to y not explained.

Comment: @totyped Come on..

Comment: @totyped So if you want more details that are a lot to say : $g,h \in L^1$, look at the Fubini theorem, $L^1 \cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$, the FT is a bounded (continuous) operator on $L^2$ and also on the space of tempered distributions so the convolution theorems stay true also for $g,h \in L^2$ or $g,h \in S'(\mathbb{R})$ the space of tempered distributions

Comment: @user1952009 Well, you start of with h(x), then you take it's Fourier Transform, within the Fourier Transform, you change x to y, but only for one x, since you keep the x from g(x).

Comment: @totyped Useless detail.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, this is because Fourier modes are eigenfunctions of translation operators: 
$$\underbrace{e^{ik(x-p)}}_{\text{translated function}} = \underbrace{e^{-ipk}}_{\text{scalar}} ~ \underbrace{e^{ikx}}_{\text{original function}}.$$A convolution operator is build up from sums or integrals of translation operators, and hence Fourier modes also diagonalize convolution operators. The function-space analog of a diagonal matrix is a multiplication operator.

Making this precise requires some functional analysis, but this is the basic idea and the correct intuition.

Comment: In that case it is a good idea to start by looking at how it works for the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), where you can write that the (circular) convolution operator $g[n] \mapsto g \ast h[n]$ is a linear operator i.e. a matrix $g \ast h = M g$ and it can be diagonalized $M = W H W^*$ where $W$ is the discrete FT operator (again a matrix) and $H$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal the discrete FT of $h[n]$

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform is the decompostion of a signal as a sum of sinuoids.

When you convolve two such sums, by the superposition principle you get a double sum of convolved sinusoids. By orthogonality, the individual convolutions amount to Dirac deltas (modulated by the phase shift). Hence, the Fourier decomposition of a convolution is given by the product of the coefficients where the frequencies match.

Informally, for every component of the first signal
$$a_ie^{i\omega t}*\sum_j b_je^{j\omega t}=\sum_j a_i b_j(e^{i\omega t}*e^{j\omega t})=\sum_j a_ib_j\delta_{ij}=a_ib_i.$$

(Summations are understood in a broad sense.)

Comment: Let $f(t) = e^{i \omega_1 t},g(t) = e^{i \omega_2 t}$, how do you define $f \ast g(t)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: don't try trolling.

Comment: Not at all, this is a deep question

Comment: I don't think you know the answer (which is complicated). So how do you define $f \ast g(t)$ ?

Comment: Also see what Nick Alger wrote, which means that with $f(t)=e^{i \omega t}$ then $f \ast \delta(t-a)= e^{i \omega a} f(t)$ and which is correct (in the context of the theory of distributions). But what you wrote isn't.

Comment: 1st of all what you wrote is not correct, did you mean $\sum_k b_k e^{i k t}$ ? In the context of Fourier series, the convolution is circular, that is with $g,h$ both $1$-periodic : $g \ast h (t) = \int_a^{a+1} g(x)h(t-x)dx$ which is $1$-periodic too. And $e^{2i \pi  n t} \ast e^{2i \pi  k t} =  \int_a^{a+1} e^{2i \pi n x} e^{2i \pi  k (t-x)}dx = e^{2i \pi  k t}\int_a^{a+1} e^{2i \pi (n-k) x}dx = e^{2i \pi  k t} 1_{n = k}$. But in the context of the Fourier transform you can't write anything like this, because the Fourier transform isn't directly the limiting case of the Fourier series.

Comment: Even in with of the theory of distributions, trying to generalize this to the Fourier transform is really not easy.