# Does the translation operator for an arbitrary function always exist?

Tags: operator-theory

$\newcommand{\bvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{#1}}}$
The following question is very much about a mathematical detail in a physics derivation, but I would like to hear what the mathematicians have to say, and if there's any recommended resources for me to look into.

In a proof of the [Bloch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem) in *Ashcroft & Mermin's Solid State Physics*, it uses the translational operator $T_\bvec{R}$ with respect to a translation vector $\bvec{R}$ such that for any function $f(\bvec{r})$
$$ T_\bvec{R}f(\bvec{r}) = f(\bvec{r}+\bvec{R}). $$

I am wondering if such an operator always exists for any function $f(\bvec{r}): \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ we can think of, and if they can be explicitly constructed.

A simple enough example I can think of right now is
$$ T_\bvec{R} = e^{i\bvec{k}\cdot\bvec{R}} $$
for the function
$$ f(\bvec{r}) = e^{i\bvec{k}\cdot\bvec{r}}. $$

Comment: As your example gets at, Fourier modes diagonalize the translation operator. So you can translate a function by taking its Fourier transform, pointwise multiplying by $e^{ik\cdot R}$, then taking the inverse Fourier transform of the resultant function. This can sometimes be a useful way to think about translation, particularly when considering linear combinations of different translations (since Fourier modes diagonalize them all). [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041777/3060) may also be useful

Comment: @NickAlger this is insightful, maybe you could expand it into an answer? A question: what do you mean by *"Fourier modes diagonalise the translation operator"*?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T_{\bf{R}}$ is an operator which is applied
to *functions*. In this particular case the codomain also consists of functions. And the definition is as you have written: If $T_{\bf R}f=g$ then $g({\bf r})=f(\bf r+\bf R)$ for all $\bf r$ by definition.

Comment: How does this show that $T_\boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}$ necessarily exists?

Comment: If $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $g$ as defined in my answer does the same, and $g=T_{\bf R} f$.